# Allow second image to be loaded when clicked on first- whilst maintaining WR.CSS style.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a basic html/css template from W3.CSS link [here](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_portfolio2.htm)

There is a division that displays images like so:

```
<div class="w3-third">
<img src="/w3images/boy.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Quiet day at the beach. Cold, but beautiful">
<img src="/w3images/man_bench.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Waiting for the bus in the desert">
<img src="/w3images/natureboy.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Nature again.. At its finest!">
</div>
```

And javascript that enlarges the image upon click

```
 <!-- Modal for full size images on click-->
  <div id="modal01" class="w3-modal w3-black" style="padding-top:0" onclick="this.style.display='none'">
    <span class="w3-button w3-black w3-xlarge w3-display-topright">×</span>
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom w3-center w3-transparent w3-padding-64">
      <img id="img01" class="w3-image">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>
```

How can I modify this code so that another image is loaded over the original image instead?

Reasoning: I like this style of image loading, and would like to have the user click on the image so that a new second image relating to the first one is loaded.

Comment: Do you mean that upon clicking an image, another image will load on the black screen?

Comment: Why in the world are you using anything that originated from w3schools??!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your html:

```
<img src="/w3images/natureboy.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick('second-image-ocean')" alt="A boy surrounded by beautiful nature">

<img src="/w3images/ocean.jpg" style="display:none" id="second-image-ocean" alt="This ocean really reminds me of a boy...">

<img src="/w3images/girl_mountain.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick('second-image-trees')" alt="What a beautiful scenery this sunset">

<img src="/w3images/trees.jpg" style="display:none" id="second-image-trees" alt="These trees really remind me of a girl...">
```

And in your JavaScript change the function onClick to this:

```
function onClick(id) {
  element = document.getElementById(id);
  document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src;
  document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "block";
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  captionText.innerHTML = element.alt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that was spot on - I will up vote once i get enough points to do so.